# How to bind the GroupBy of two different Xamdatagrids?

Tags: wpf, group-by, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have two xamdatagrids with same column structure and are binded with two different datatables from my viewmodel.

I am trying to achieve a scenario where if I apply Group By to any column of  grid1 , the grid2 should also be grouped in a similar way.

Is there any event which I can use to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this functionality by using the `Grouping` event of the `XamDataGrid` control.

First, define the `Grouping` event handler in the XAML:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="Grid1" Grouping="Grid1_Grouping">
```

Second, add the following code for `Grid1_Grouping`:

```
private void Grid1_Grouping(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.GroupingEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear all previous items from the groups collection
    Grid2.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.Clear();

    // Add the same groups set as currently defined in the Grid1 
    foreach (var g in e.Groups)
    {
        Grid2.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.Add(new FieldSortDescription { FieldName = g.FieldName, Direction = g.Direction, IsGroupBy = g.IsGroupBy });
    }
}
```